# Custom event listeners in an express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, events, dom-events

What is the best way of handling custom event listeners in an express route?

I'm probably doing it all wrong but here's what I have at the moment:

```
module.exports = {
    get: function(req, res, next) { 

        MyModel.on('error', function(err) {
          res.send(501)
        })

        MyModel.on('found', function() {
          res.send(200)
        })

        MyModel.on('notFound', function() {
          res.send(404)
        })

        MyModel.findByName(req.params.name);
      }
}
```

I can see this is totally wrong since each event listener will be added on each request.

It also feels wrong to start passing the response object around to facilitate responding when an event is fired.

I could just use callbacks on the `findByName` method but I really like tying into the event system but I'm just wondering how to handle this situation better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use event bindings for this, use the callback function:

```
module.exports = {
    get: function(req, res, next) {
        MyModel.findByName(req.params.name, function (error, model) {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(501).send(error);
            }
            if (!model) {
                return res.status(404).send('Not found');
            }
            res.send(model.toJSON());
        });
      }
}
```

To add some clarification based on the comments, your example is using express and mongoose, both by the same original author and both primarily oriented with functional style programming and callbacks. While it is possible to design frameworks to use events, callbacks, or both/either (optional), in these 2 specific cases the library forces you to use callbacks because it doesn't provide events for these particular operations. That's why for express and mongoose for these particular calls, callbacks are the idomatic thing.

Now looking at your example, mongoose does emit some events at the Model class level, but those are not associated with an express request/response and thus are more appropriate for error logging and exception handling and some other specialized use cases outside of basic web application response rendering.

So when I said "don't user event bindings *for this*", I didn't mean event bindings are never appropriate, just that given your specific code snippet, they are neither supported by the libraries you are using nor idiomatic for this example of a basic make-a-db-query-and-send-back-a-web-page scenario.

Comment: I originially had it like this but i was trying to limit the amount of  nesting which can happen from using callbacks. I guess in this situation it will work and add event listeners when things need to go deeper.

Comment: 2 things: 1 if you aren't down with callbacks, you are using the wrong programming environment, period. It's like trying to do lisp except you hate parentheses. 2. Event listeners on the Model classes itself will only handle events not already handled by callbacks and won't structure your program correctly to give you access to the request & response objects you need. Manage nesting with using named functions and flow control libraries, but callbacks and baked into the core of node.

Comment: I have no problem with callbacks at all but it's about choosing the correct tools for the job. Event Listeners are also a very core part of node (infact the event loop is what makes node so powerful). Please be more constructive.

Comment: I agree with @PeterLyons about the use of events. Use events for notifying, broadcasting and message passing, use callbacks for flow control. Take a look at https://github.com/caolan/async for flow control. There are some other flow control libraries but async has been my favorite. If used in combination with http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/ you can get your flow control down to an art and you'll get away from nesting hell, as well as much better error handling.